# Изменение ширины пунктов выпадающего списка

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приветствую. Есть такое меню, с обычным выпадающим списком:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видим, это обычная подача с абсолютной позицией и выпадающими пунктами вниз. Однако, пунктов стало много и появилась необходимость сделать пункты в несколько колонок. Проблем с этим нет, задать `position: relative` для первого списка и сместить вложенный список влево со 100% шириной.

Итак, вопрос. Точнее 2 вопроса:
**1)** Как по средствам JS превратить выпадающий список в многоколоночную подачу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама стилистика прописана изначально, прописан `column-width` и `column-gap`. То есть, нужно определить ширину родителя и задать её для вложенного списка. С этим справится не сложно:

```
function resize(){$('#sub').width($('#nav').width())}resize();
$( window ).resize(function() {resize()});
```

Только вот меню будет идти не от начала родителя, так как `position: relative` задан для пункта списк в котором находится второй пункт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как посчитать ширину пунктов впереди идущих и сместить выпадающий список в начало?

**2)** Опять же, по средствам JS, высчитать ширину впереди идущих пунктов и отнять от полученной ширины родителя. Чтоб получилось вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, чем ближе пункт к краю, тем уже становится выпадающий список по ширине. Плюс, установить минимальное значение в 240рх. Добавляю код для примера с простым выпадающим списком для тестов:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
}

.menu li span {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .sub {
  position: relative;
}

.menu .sub ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-column-width: 200px;
  -moz-column-width: 200px;
  column-width: 200px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
  -moz-column-gap: 2em;
  column-gap: 2em;
  min-width: 240px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #333;
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.menu .sub ul:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 7px 7px 7px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #333;
}

.menu .sub:hover ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu .sub:hover ul:before {
  top: -7px;
}

.menu .sub ul li {
  float: none;
}

.menu .sub ul span {
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.menu .sub ul span:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a class="active" href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li class="sub">
    <a href="#"><span>Wedding collections</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Crystal Design Haute Couture </span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Crystal Sevilia Campaign</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Nora Naviano</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Naviblue</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Crystal Design Barcelona and Flower</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Oksana Mukha</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Oksana Mukha</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Innocentia</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Eva Santorini</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Eva Pink</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Pollardi</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Lussano</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Ariamo</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Tesoro</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Lanesta</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Armonia</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Dominiss</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Dominiss</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Lite</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Eva Lendel</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Daniela Di Marino</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Monica Loretti</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Monica</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Mary</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Mary</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Tiara</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Serenada</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub">
    <a href="#"><span>Evening collections</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Crystal Santorini Campaign</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Crystal Astoria Campaign</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Rebel</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Oksana Mukha</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Pollardi</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Mary</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Dominiss</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Duet</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub">
    <a href="/stuff/accesories/3"><span>Accesories</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Veils</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Jackets</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Boleroes</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Belts</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Cooperation</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Contacts</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Спасибо за помощь, особенно за готовый пример. Если долго описывать, хотя бы укажите, что потребуется сделать на словах.

PS: Повторюсь, что знаю о решении через CSS. Интересен именно вариант с использованием JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы выпадающего меню всегда совпадало по краю с основным, сдвинем его при помощи `margin-left` на нужное количество пикселей. Для этого подсчитаем координаты основного и выпадающего меню методом `.offset().left` и вычтем из координат основного координаты субменю — так мы получим отрицательное значение и присвоим его `margin-left`.

Для примера разбил субменю на 4 колонки. Добавил пунктам флексбокс-раскладку, с расположением в колонку и переносом. Осталось посчитать высоту для меню — для этого будем суммировать высоту каждого 4-го пункта (поскольку у нас 4 колонки) и затем присвоим ее субменю. Также нам нужна ширина, равная всему меню, потому возьмем ширину экрана — 100vw — и вычтем из неё расстояние до левого края экрана. Примем за аксиому, что меню центрируется, а значит слева и справа одинаковое расстояние, потому это расстояние просто умножаем на 2; в итоге получаем строку `.width('calc(100vw - ' + menuOffset.left * 2 + 'px)')`.

Все эти операции делаем при событии `mouseover` (первая функция в `.hover()`) и добавляем в инлайн-стили субменю, при `mouseout` (вторая функция в `.hover()`) очищаем инлайн-стили.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sub').hover(function() {
    var menuOffset = $('.menu').offset();
    var subMenuOffset = $('ul', this).offset();
    var heightSum = 0;
    
    // так сдвигаем влево на уровень с меню выпадающее субменю
    $('ul', this).css('margin-left', menuOffset.left - subMenuOffset.left);
    
    $('li', this).each(function(index) {
      if(index % 4 == 0) heightSum += +$(this).height();
    });
    
    $('ul', this).height(heightSum).width('calc(100vw - ' + menuOffset.left * 2 + 'px)');
  }, function() {
    $('ul', this).removeAttr('style');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
}

.menu li span {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .sub {
  position: relative;
}

.menu .sub ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  min-width: 240px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #333;
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.menu .sub ul li {
  width: 200px;
}

.menu .sub:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 7px);
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 7px 7px 7px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #333;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu .sub:hover ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu .sub:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu .sub:hover ul:before {
  top: -7px;
}

.menu .sub ul li {
  float: none;
}

.menu .sub ul span {
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.menu .sub ul span:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a class="active" href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li class="sub">
    <a href="#"><span>Wedding collections</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Crystal Design Haute Couture </span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Crystal Sevilia Campaign</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Nora Naviano</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Naviblue</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Crystal Design Barcelona and Flower</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Oksana Mukha</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Oksana Mukha</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Innocentia</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Eva Santorini</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Eva Pink</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Pollardi</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Lussano</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Ariamo</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Tesoro</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Lanesta</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Armonia</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Dominiss</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Dominiss</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Lite</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Eva Lendel</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Daniela Di Marino</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Monica Loretti</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Monica</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Mary</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Mary</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Tiara</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Serenada</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub">
    <a href="#"><span>Evening collections</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Crystal Santorini Campaign</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Crystal Astoria Campaign</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Rebel</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Oksana Mukha</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Pollardi</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Mary</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Dominiss</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Duet</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub">
    <a href="/stuff/accesories/3"><span>Accesories</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Veils</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Jackets</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Boleroes</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Belts</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Cooperation</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Contacts</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Альтернативный вариант, где от JS требуется только сдвинуть субменю влево и задать ширину:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sub').hover(function() {
    var menuOffset = $('.menu').offset();
    var subMenuOffset = $('ul', this).offset();
    
    // так сдвигаем влево на уровень с меню выпадающее субменю
    $('ul', this).css('margin-left', menuOffset.left - subMenuOffset.left);
    
    $('.sub ul').width($('.menu').width()); 
  }, function() {
    $('ul', this).removeAttr('style');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
}

.menu li span {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu .sub {
  position: relative;
}

.menu .sub ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-column-width: 200px;
  -moz-column-width: 200px;
  column-width: 200px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
  -moz-column-gap: 2em;
  column-gap: 2em;
  min-width: 240px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #333;
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.menu .sub ul li {
  width: 200px;
}

.menu .sub:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 7px);
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 7px 7px 7px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #333;
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu .sub:hover ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu .sub:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu .sub:hover ul:before {
  top: -7px;
}

.menu .sub ul li {
  float: none;
}

.menu .sub ul span {
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.menu .sub ul span:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a class="active" href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li class="sub">
    <a href="#"><span>Wedding collections</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Crystal Design Haute Couture </span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Crystal Sevilia Campaign</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Nora Naviano</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Naviblue</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Crystal Design Barcelona and Flower</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Oksana Mukha</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Oksana Mukha</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Innocentia</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Eva Santorini</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Eva Pink</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Pollardi</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Lussano</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Ariamo</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Tesoro</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Lanesta</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Armonia</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Dominiss</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Dominiss</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Lite</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Eva Lendel</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Daniela Di Marino</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Monica Loretti</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Monica</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Mary</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Mary</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Tiara</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Serenada</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub">
    <a href="#"><span>Evening collections</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Crystal Santorini Campaign</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Crystal Astoria Campaign</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Rebel</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Oksana Mukha</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Pollardi</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Mary</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Dominiss</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Duet</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub">
    <a href="/stuff/accesories/3"><span>Accesories</span></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Veils</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Jackets</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Boleroes</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Belts</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Cooperation</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span>Contacts</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь стало понятна вторая часть скрипта. А для чего было так усложнять разбивку на колонки? Ведь там был `column-width`, то есть, достаточно было задашь ширину и начальную позицию выпадающего блока, остальное все само выстраивалось. И как насчет кроссбраузерности? Сам стиль calc не дружит с многими браузерами.

Comment: С колонками у меня так и не получилось сделать, у них не до конца подвластный моему пониманию контекст форматирования ) Колонки на флексе гораздо более управляемы и понятны (а также кроссбраузерны).
Что касается кроссбраузерного использования `calc()`, то из десктопных браузеров его не поддерживает совсем ИЕ8-. Вы все еще это поддерживаете?

Comment: Можно колонки и на flexbox использовать. Это не существенно, просто было интересно, для чего усложнять подачу разбивкой на колонки через JS. Ведь [так](http://codepen.io/pen/MmYEJj) получится намного короче, только теперь треугольник нужно сместить к пункту. И проще редактировать. Добавил класс в пункт списка и количество колонок выпадающего блока в нем изменилось, а так все формируется через скрипт и гибкость пропадает.

Comment: Это да, тут я немного перемудрил, не надо ночью на вопросы начинать отвечать :-) Слишком буквально воспринял, что все надо сделать при помощи JS.

Comment: Я так то сразу и не понял вторую часть, после объяснения все разобрал. Добавьте тогда в ответ и коротки вариант, чтоб я не добавлял уже сюда и свой ответ, ток в него нужно добавить resize, а то прокрутка появляется при сужении и треугольник сместить. Я чуть позже могу из дома доделать код который выше присылал, думаю, с этим справлюсь без проблем. Но, его точно нужно добавить как альтернативу, думаю, другим будет полезно. И второй вариант с уменьшением ширины. В скрипте теперь вместо `margin-left` ширину подставить и будет полный ответ.

Comment: Теперь понял, почему вы не использовали `.resize`, не сразу обратил внимание на `.hover`. Правда тогда нужно `$('ul', this).removeAttr('style');` заменить на `$('ul').removeAttr('style');`. Так как после наведения ширина  выпадающего блока останется и появится прокрутка. Так же, нужно учитывать внутренний отступ, из-за него ширина получается на 40px больше. Плюс, я бы все же сделал через resize, так как длинный список вниз может создавать прокрутку на невысоких страницах. В общем, по той же ссылке можете глянуть. Еще раз спасибо за помощь!