# Выравнивание выпадающего меню на css

Tags: css, menu

Создал меню на css, но проблема в том, что выпадающее меню должно быть не прямо под пунктом меню, на которое навели курсор, а должно занимать всю ширину контейнера под пунктом меню, как на рисунке.
Подскажите, как это правильно реализовать на css?
Верхнее меню смещено вправо, слева ещё может быть логотип, т.е. напротив item1,item2,item3.
и чтобы было адаптивное выпадающее меню, т.е. при уменьшении разрешения выпадающее меню также занимало всю ширину.
и ещё нужны треугольники, как на рисунке при наведении на пункт меню.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        header{
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .wrapper{
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .wrapper:after{
            content: '';
            display: block;
            clear: both;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        nav{
            width: 50%;
            float: right;
            clear: both;
        }
        .item{
            float: left;
            margin-right: 30px;
        }
        .dropdown{
            display: none;
        }
        .drop:hover + .dropdown{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            background: green;
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="drop" href="#">item1</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><p>item</p></li>
                        <li><p>item</p></li>
                        <li><p>item</p></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="drop" href="#">item2</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><p>item</p></li>
                        <li><p>item</p></li>
                        <li><p>item</p></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="drop" href="#">item3</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><p>item</p></li>
                        <li><p>item</p></li>
                        <li><p>item</p></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вот вам готовый [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653422/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) с удобным решением

Comment: @Alexey Giryayev, вы хоть читали полностью мою проблему?
или вы прочитали только заглавие темы и через поиск нашли похожее заглавие? в моей теме где-то говорится про js? или тему до конца читать сейчас не модно?

Comment: @Alexey Giryayev, без js такое сможете сделать?

Comment: Это был мой вопрос. Именно с такой подачей меню. Без JS вы не сможете выставить треугольник в нужном пункте. Само меню растянуть не проблема.

Comment: а это мой вопрос, который с вашим вопросом ничего общего не имеет.
без js я смогу сделать треугольник, допустим с помощью псевдоэлемента after. Основная проблема в выравнивании выпадающего меню

Comment: у кого какие идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать трегульничек из границ и добавить его псевдоэлементом:

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

.item {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
  /*position: relative;*/
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
}

.item:hover .drop+.dropdown {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.item:hover .drop::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
  margin: 5px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="item">
          <a class="drop" href="#">item1</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>
              <p>item</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>item</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>item</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <div class="dropa"></div>
          <a class="drop" href="#">item2</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>
              <p>item</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>item</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>item</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a class="drop" href="#">item3</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li>
              <p>item</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>item</p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>item</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: блин, нужно было просто убрать position: relative, благодарю

Comment: @word, если вы про оный у `.item`, то у вас его и не было

Comment: ну значит нужно было просто поставить left:0;
в основном коде у меня есть position: relative, как-то сразу не обратил внимание